# Get values from a column where a threshold is crossed for the first time for each group in R

Tags: r

I have a list of transactions for a lot of people. I wish to find out when each particular person has crossed a particular threshold value of total transactions.

Here is an example of what I have already done:
Example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(name = rep(c("a","b"),4), 
    dates = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 8), amt = 11:18)
setorderv(df, "name")
```

This gives me the following data frame

```
  name      dates amt
1    a 2017-01-01  11
3    a 2017-03-01  13
5    a 2017-05-01  15
7    a 2017-07-01  17
2    b 2017-02-01  12
4    b 2017-04-01  14
6    b 2017-06-01  16
8    b 2017-08-01  18
```

Then I wrote the following code to find the cumulative sums

```
df$cumsum <- ave(df$amt, df$name, FUN = cumsum)
```

This gives me the following data frame:

```
  name      dates amt cumsum
1    a 2017-01-01  11     11
3    a 2017-03-01  13     24
5    a 2017-05-01  15     39
7    a 2017-07-01  17     56
2    b 2017-02-01  12     12
4    b 2017-04-01  14     26
6    b 2017-06-01  16     42
8    b 2017-08-01  18     60
```

Now I want to know when each person crossed 20 and 40. I wrote the following code to find this out:

```
names <- unique(df$name)    
for (i in seq_along(names)){
    x1 <- Position(function(x) x >= 20, df$cumsum[df$name == names[i]])
    x2 <- Position(function(x) x >= 40, df$cumsum[df$name == names[i]])

    result_df[i,] <- c(df$name[i], 
                         df[df$name == names[i],2][x1],
                         df[df$name == names[i],2][x2])
}
```

This code checks where the thresholds were crossed and stores the row number in a variable. Then extracts the value from that row of the second column and stores it in a another data frame.

The problem is, this code is really slow. I have over 200,000 people in my data set and over 10 million rows. This code takes about 25 seconds to execute for the first 50 users, which means it is likely to take about 30 hours for the entire dataset.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With dplyr you could group by person, filter when cumsum is above >20 or above >40, and then use slice(1) to select the first relevant row per person. Should be way faster than for looping.

```
df <- read.table(text = '
name      dates amt cumsum
a 2017-01-01  11     11
a 2017-03-01  13     24
a 2017-05-01  15     39
a 2017-07-01  17     56
b 2017-02-01  12     12
b 2017-04-01  14     26
b 2017-06-01  16     42
b 2017-08-01  18     60', header = T)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(cumsum > 20) %>% 
  slice(1)

       name      dates   amt cumsum
      <fctr> <fctr> <int>  <int>
1      a 2017-03-01    13     24
2      b 2017-04-01    14     26

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(cumsum > 40) %>% 
  slice(1)

   name      dates   amt cumsum
  <fctr>     <fctr> <int>  <int>
      a 2017-07-01    17     56
      b 2017-06-01    16     42
```

Of course you could subsequently rbind these dataframes and arrange on person. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked for me. The entire operation was done in about 70 seconds.

Comment: Great! Just wanted to add the following: with my code I assumed your cumsum variable was arranged in increasing order per person, which is logically the case after your cumsum command. If it had been in random order, you could have replaced the last line by slice(which.min(cumsum)) to filter the rows with the lowest cumsum values above 20 or above 40.

Comment: Yes, the cumsum was arranged in ascending order. But thanks for this tip, might come in handy in other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Using data table could be something like this:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(df[order(df$dates), ])

dt[ ,':='(minDate20 = min(dates[cumsum(amt) > 20]), minDate40 = min(dates[cumsum(amt) > 40])), by = .(name)]


dt[dates == minDate20, ]
dt[dates == minDate40, ]
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked, but was slightly slower than the other solution using Dplyr package.

Comment: o yes? I often use data table cause is faster than dplyr, but I will start to try dplyr again to check that

Comment: That's true in my experience as well. In fact, at times I have found dplyr to be painfully slow. But for this particular operation, dplyr was surprisingly fast. In general I like dplyr because I'm sort of a beginner and dplyr's syntax is more intuitive than data.table's.